# Cassandra multiple keyspaces or column families?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, scalability, bigdata

I'm currently working in a product where I have to store [activities](http://activitystrea.ms/) on Cassandra DB. Since our activities are coming from a multi-tenant application environment we need to model our data in tenant aware manner. What is the best approach we can take to scale?

1. Create key-space per tenant
2. Store activities in a single key-space with proper tenant aware secondary index.

For the publishing purpose we are going to re-use existing WSO2-BAM data publisher and for the retrieving purpose CQL will be used.

Appreciate your thoughts and previous experience about this.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use one keyspace and multiple column families, primarily because the activities you are storing seem like one logical set of data.

If you use multiple keyspaces, your application would have to contain some logic to figure out which one to query. I think this type of logic is better pushed down into Cassandra (via a tenant aware index).

Comment: At the moment I do have two activity types, but this number might grow with new feature additions.But still I don't need to to lookup based on activity type.